# ReactJS onBlur exclusions

Tags: reactjs, onblur

My react app renders a text input that has functions to handle both onKeyDown (uses a conditional to check whether the key is 'Enter' or 'Backspace') and onBlur.  Both 'Enter' and 'Backspace' result in focusing on a different input, and consequently triggers onBlur, which makes a fetch call that I don't want it to.  What can I do to exclude pressing Enter and Backspace from triggering onBlur?  I've seen some solutions in other frameworks but this question is specific to react.

```
handleKeyDown = (event) => {
   if(event.key == 'Enter') 
      //adds new object via fetch(), focuses on new input
   if(event.key == 'Backspace' && !event.target.value)
      //deletes current object via fetch(), focuses on previous input
}

handleOnBlur = (event) => {
   //edits existing item via fetch()
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {displayData.map((item, i) => (
       <div>
         <input
           value={item}
           onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
           onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)}
           onBlur={this.handleOnBlur.bind(this)} />
       </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
```

I am trying to make it so a keydown of Enter or Backspace does not trigger an onblur event, the blur event does not have a key property so I was unable to begin the handleOnBlur function with the conditional `if(event.key !== 'Backspace' || event.target.value)`, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide some code snippets, so it is easier for us to grasp the problem and help you out?

Comment: I'd use `onChange`, and if you continue w/ `onBlur`, keep track of the control state (value), and only fetch if fetching is needed.

Comment: @GlebKost just posted, apologies for leaving that out initially.

Comment: @Napoli, now that code is there could you be more specific with how you would handle value?

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to do something like this, keep track of a local variable which notifies the `onBlur` to proceed w/ a fetch?

```
constructor() {
    ...
    this.isBlurKeyDownInvoked = false;
}

handleKeyDown = (event) => {
   if(event.key == 'Enter')  {
      this.isBlurKeyDownInvoked = true;

      //adds new object via fetch(), focuses on new input
   }
   if(event.key == 'Backspace' && !event.target.value)
      this.isBlurKeyDownInvoked = true;

      //deletes current object via fetch(), focuses on previous input
   }
}      

handleOnBlur = (event) => {
    if (this.isBlurKeyDownInvoked) {
        this.isBlurKeyDownInvoked = false;
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```